# How do I Detect (and Delete) a File if it is Empty using a Windows Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How do I detect if a file is empty using a Windows batch file? I want to delete error logs if they are empty.

I am aware for for loop solutions such as https://web.archive.org/web/20171110203759/http://anderwald.info/scripting/windows-batch-delete-all-empty-files-in-a-specified-folder/ but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution if you know the specific single file in question that needs to be tested, as I may not wish to delete other zero byte files in the folder.

Answer (score 33):

The link you cited used the following to delete all 0 length files

```
for /F "delims=" "%I" in ('dir /B') do if not exist "%I\" if %~zI EQU 0 del "%I"
```

That is more complicated and not as efficient as it could be. It is much simpler to simply use:

```
for %F in (*) do if %~zF equ 0 del "%F"
```

You want to delete a specific file if it is zero length. So just substitute your file name for the `*` wild card.

```
for %F in ("yourFileName") do if %~zF equ 0 del "%F"
```

If you are going to use this in a batch file than you need to double all the percents (`%%F`, `%%~zF`)

If you don't want to use a FOR loop, you can use a CALL parameter instead - it uses the same modifiers as FOR variables. However, CALL is slower than FOR (probably not significant in your case)

```
@echo off
call :deleteIfEmpty "yourFileName"
exit /b

:deleteIfEmpty
if %~z1 eq 0 del %1
exit /b
```

EDIT

I've thought of yet another way. A FINDSTR search string of `"^"` will match all lines of a file. But an empty file doesn't have any lines. So simply delete the file if FINDSTR fails to match a line.

```
>nul findstr "^" "yourFileName" || del "yourFileName"
```

Comment: Hmmm... so I thought of this too, using a for loop for only one iteration on my file. I was hoping there was something more elegant than this, but this will do.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette I added an alternative using CALL instead of FOR

Comment: @MatthewDoucette - I've added yet another method using FINDSTR. I also fixed a silly bug in the CALL solution (too many colons in label).

Comment: Good to see this question not only answered, but also explained and generalized!

Comment: for recursive file search, do `for /r %F`. To suppress the output, use `@` symbol before if command- `@if`. Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014662/can-i-shut-down-echo-for-this-for-cycle-inputed-from-cmd/18014912#18014912 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176962/recursively-delete-0kb-files-using-windows-cmd

Comment: dbenham's simplfied findstr command worked perfect for my needs since I know exactly what file I need to check to see if it's empty.

Comment: Which of these is the fastest?

Comment: note: in a batch file those should be `%%F` instead of `%F` (all `%` should be substituted with `%%`)

Answer (score 6):

The `forfiles` command might be nicer, like this:

echo

```
forfiles /c "cmd /c if @fsize==0  echo @file"
```

delete

```
forfiles /c "cmd /c if @fsize==0  del @file"
```

Do what you want

Comment: FORFILES is not universally available to all versions of Windows. It is also very S L O W . . . .

Comment: @dbenham It's true, but you have one big advantage in this solution: You can specify the filesize you need. You can also find "empty"/useless files with 4 or 5 bytes size (only including a CR or CR/LF or another control character in addition to a UTF-8-BOM). I know that 1 or 2 bytes you could also include A or ZZ, but this would be useless as log file as well .-)

Comment: How do you specify folder path?

Comment: this finds folders as empty files, which may be undesirable

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to make a macro that can actually **delete empty files and empty folders** within a folder hierarchy.

I took me a while to fiddle it out, but now it works:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET topLevel=%cd%
FOR /D /R %%D IN (*) DO ( 
  CD %%D
  FOR %%F IN (*) DO IF %%~zF EQU 0 DEL "%%F"
)
CD %topLevel%
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%D IN (`"DIR/AD/B/S|SORT/R"`) DO RD "%%D"
```

It first disables echoing (remove @ECHO OFF if you want to read what actually happens).
Then it stores the current folder in topLevel variable.
Next is to walk trough all folders "%D" using the FOR command in the current folder and all sub folders.
It changes local directory to each of the sub folders found (CD %%D).
Within each sub folder using another FOR loop it finds and deletes all files %%F for which the filesize (~z for %%~zF) is 0.
When this entire dual loop is done all empty files are effectively killed from the disk.
Now a new FOR command is exectuted to perform a RD %%D to remove every directory.
Due to DOS being safe here it will delete only EMPTY folders. Folders with files inside keep intact.

**But hey, who says you can't improve once more?**

I've revamped the script once more, now **heavily optimized** for **speedy processing**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET topLevel=%CD%
FOR /D /R %%D IN (*) DO (
  CD %%D 
  CALL :innerLoop
)
CD %topLevel%
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%D IN (`"DIR /AD/B/S | SORT /R"`) DO RD "%%D"
GOTO :break

:innerLoop
  FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR/B/A-D/OS') DO IF %%~zF EQU 0 (DEL "%%F") ELSE (GOTO :break)

:break
```

The problem with the previous one was that the two nested FOR loops touched every single file. As empty files are rare, there is absolutely no need to touch every file and its a big waste of time. I've tried to run it on a 25 TByte volume with ~5 million files..

So I modified the inner loop to sort files by size in a DIR command using the /OS (Ordered Size) option. The /A-D option does not list directories, so only true files remain (directories are listed as size 0 too, this is why I added this). For every file the size is checked. Once a file larger than 0 bytes is found, the loop is exited using the GOTO :break. As the files are sorted by size, smallest first, its safe to proceed like this. A huge timesafer!

As DOS FOR command has no elegant way to leave the loop I used this strange construct to call the inner loop using GOTO :break.

It seems to run about **a few thousand times faster** on my large volume than the previous one ;-)

I hope you like it!

Best regards,
Axel Mertes

PS: The biggest nightmare in DOS scripting is understanding when you need %% or %, ' or " etc.

Comment: Your optimized version is nicely done, however, it is not an answer to the question. The OP explicitly asked how to test and delete a single specific file, not an entire hierarchy. Also, you have developed a batch script, not a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I normally would create a vbscript file with the FileSystemObject that would handle the detection and deletion of the file, and run it from a batch file.

**VBScript File:**

```
Dim oFSO
Dim oFile
Dim ts
strFilePath = "<insert path to file here>"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if oFSO.FileExists(strFilePath) then
   Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile(strFilePath)
   strLine = ""
   linecount = 0
   blnShouldDelete = True
   Set ts = oFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
   Do While ts.AtEndOfStream <> True
      linecount = linecount + 1
      strLine = ts.ReadLine

      if Len(strLine) > 0 then
         blnShouldDelete = False
      end if 
   Loop
   ts.Close

   if (linecount = 0 Or linecount = 1) And blnShouldDelete = True then
       oFile.Delete
   end if
end if
set oFSO = Nothing
```

**For the Batch file:**

```
cscript <filename>.vbs  
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

simple is to find the number of lines in the file using

```
   findstr /R /N "^" file.txt | find /C ":"
```

now if its count is zero then delete using if conditions.

you can use the loop through files and check for all files in folders