# avoid creating empty STDOUT and STDERR files

Tags: .net, command-line, batch-file, console-application

When you specify STDOUT and STDERR files...

```
cmd.exe < "C:\in.txt" 1> "C:\out.txt" 2> "C:\err.txt"
```

...you end up creating a file even if that particular file stream was never written to within the console app (cmd.exe).  Can this be avoided?  I would rather not produce empty files.

Comment: It may be a ugly workaround, but you could check the size of stdout and stderr and erase them if they are empty at the end of your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are created by the `cmd.com` before running your program, so you have no control over it. The best you can do is making a batch file that "cleans up" after running your process by deleting `out.txt` and/or `err.txt` when they are empty.

Here is [a link to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9378972/335858) explaining how to detect and delete empty files.